# How to assign lowest index value to newest row or sort in reverse order

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I have a news ticker sort of thing with the items stored in mysql rows. I want to display the most recent news first, so I need to iterate through the table one row at a time from the newest entries to the oldest. I'm trying to iterate based on an auto-increment index column, by using i++ to increment the value of the index in the SELECT statement each time it is called. The problem is that this provides the rows from the oldest to the newest, but what I want is the newest to the oldest. How can I sort the table in reverse order so that the newest entries have the lowest index value?

I am aware of ORDER BY ASC and DESC but these apply only to result sets. In my case, the result set will always be only one row, so this doesn't help. I need to sort the table itself so that the newest entries have the lowest index value, rather than sorting result sets.

The table looks something like this:

```
id      news    country     source
```

I hope to rearrange the table so the id numbers from lowest to highest correspond to the table rows from newest (most recently added) to the oldest

Comment: Why do you have only one row? Please show the table layouts you have and the PHP source code you have.

Comment: Why are you only pulling one row at a time?

Comment: Just `order by id desc limit 1` for the last row.

Comment: Implementing Nigel's suggestion, I have this (incomplete)                           <?php
session_start();
require('db.php');
if( isset( $i )) {
$_SESSION[i] = $i++;
} else {
$_SESSION[i] = 1;
}
$i = $_SESSION[i];
//limit table to only 30 entries and reset auto-increment index
if ($i <=30) {
$query = "SELECT newsitem FROM news WHERE id ='$i' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"; I fear however that this will still provide the oldest results first

Comment: I wish I new how to add a linebreak without submitting the comment. Nigel, am I wrong to think what you suggest only changes the order but does not change the correspondence between the id value and the newsitem? I see that it would give me the newest item, but I need to iterate along the items in the table.

Comment: Since I am limiting the number of table rows to 30, I could just set the value of i (the index) to 30 and then de-increment it with each call. Not elegant but should work unless someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a trigger that adjusts the new news id every time a new row is inserted

it would look something like:
Insert>Trigger called> adjust primary key

```
CREATE TRIGGER id_adjust BEFORE INSERT on news_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM news_table)=0 THEN
        SET NEW.id=999;
    ELSE
        SELECT min(id)-1 into NEW.id from news_table;
    ENDIF;
END
```

this will make sure that the latest news is always the first entry(id wise), but your index won't start with id=1.

You could also start with index=1 but if there are multiple entries in your table, that would mean you'd have to update every row with new id, increasing processing.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way since it is what I am familiar with and it works

```
if( isset($_SESSION[i]) and $_SESSION[i]!= 1){
$_SESSION[i] = --$_SESSION[i];
} else {
$_SESSION[i] = 30;
}
$i = $_SESSION[i];
$sql = "SELECT newsitem FROM news WHERE id = $i";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row["newsitem"];
}
```

I'm having trouble getting a count of rows so as to limit the table to 30 but that's a different subject.